# Is there a way to query a document based on a subdocument object ref?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose we have a schema that looks like this:

```
const RandomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  randomField: String,
  subDoc: {
    name: String,
    refDoc: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'OtherModel',
      required: true,
    },
  },
}, options);
```

Our `OtherModel` has a schema that looks like this:

```
const OtherModel = new Schema({
  name: String,
  funFact: String,
}, options);
```

From the front end of my application I'd like to query the RandomSchema model and return all instances of this model where `subDoc.refDoc.funFact === someValue`.

Is this possible? I know we have ways to populate those subdocs when return them but it happens only after matching docs have been returned, when in this case we'd need to know more than just the objectId of refDoc.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple collections are involved, this task requires use of aggregation pipeline.